# '500 - internal server error' response from firebase server on sending a downstream 'data' message

Tags: android, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending a downstream message to a single device from app server via Firebase server. I'm using the devices reg token that was passed to the apps server. app server code is

```
    $firebase_token = $request->input('token');

    $skey = env('FCM_SERVER_KEY');

    $client = new Client(['verify' => false]);

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization:key=' => $skey,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'json' => ['to' => $firebase_token, 'data' => ['message' => 'This is Genius']]
    ]);
```

I'm receiving the following message from my android app (cause i'm testing out FCM and i'm sending the `$response` back to my app on the emulator.)
Its the same message I'm getting on Postman.

```
{"message":
    "Server error: `POST https:\/\/fcm.googleapis.com\/fcm\/send` resulted in a 
    `500 Internal Server Error` response:\n
    <HTML>\n
        <HEAD>\n
            <TITLE>Internal Server Error<\/TITLE>\n
        <\/HEAD>\n
        <BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\" TEXT=\"#000000\">\n
            <H1>Internal ServerE(truncated...)\n",
"code":500, 
"status_code":500,"debug"
...
```

I'm using Laravel and Guzzle Client to deliver the message to the FCM server, I tried sending a message to my emulator from my Firebase console and it marked the message as completed but I didn't receive it on my app/emualtor. This is my `onMessageReceived` method inside my `FirebaseMessagingService` class

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}

private void showNotification(String message) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_send_icon_blue)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
```

I'm not sure whats wrong with my setup. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to receive the same response when sending from the Firebase Console?

Comment: Could you try adjusting your Authorization header to: 'Authorization' => 'key=' . $skey

Comment: @AL their is no response from firebase, but on the log of messages sent it shows a status of completed for the message

Comment: @Arthur Thompson thanks...but i'm now getting an empty response [ ] back.

Comment: What is the status code of the response?

Comment: Its working now...i am receiving the data message in the app, i am still getting the [ ] response and status code 200 OK....the notification is not showing tho but i'm guessing that is because i am sending a data message from my app server and not a notification.....thanks

Answer (score -1):

make sure that your credential is correct 
it may not received to emulator because of internet connection issues